# How can I tell Google closure compiler to not remove a var

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have the following code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

var l = window.location;
var s = 'hash';
l[s] = 'whatever i need now';
```

Which gets compiled with google closure compiler (advanced mode) like this:

```
window.location.hash="whatever i need now";
```

But in this case I really need it to keep using `l[s]= ...` in the compiled code.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to keep using the var or ignore a couple of lines?

[Compiler in action - demo](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Avar%2520l%2520%253D%2520window.location%253B%250Avar%2520s%2520%253D%2520'hash'%253B%250Al%255Bs%255D%2520%253D%2520'whatever%2520i%2520need%2520now'%253B)

Comment: Don't use advanced mode? It's experimental and may harm your code. Simple mode is usually efficient enough.

Comment: I should have said this in the question but that's not an option.

Comment: I'm curious why you would need it.  If it's used elsewhere, it should be preserved, no?

Comment: *Why* do you need to keep the `l[s]=` part? If we knew why, we might be able to help.

Comment: It's a small hack to get the hash function to work properly with junos pulse. But that's irrelevant ;-)

Comment: @yeouuu: Huh? You're going to have to explain that (probably with citations), your original code and CC's output do **exactly** the same thing. (Also: `hash` isn't a function, it's a property.) No, it's not irrelevant.

Comment: Optimize the rest of your code, keep these three lines in a different file, then concatenate both? ....... I'm running out of ideas here

Comment: Advanced mode is most certainly not experimental. It's got a long stable history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's a small hack to get the hash function to work properly with junos pulse.

I'm having a lot of trouble believing the hack is necessary, but:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

eval(
"var l = window.location;\n" +
"var s = 'hash';\n" +
"l[s] = 'whatever i need now';\n"
);
```

***hack* *cough*** :-)

Or:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

sessionStorage.x = "hash";
window.location[sessionStorage.x] = 'whatever i need now';
```

Comment: Wow that's as dirty as it can be, congratulations for using eval :)

Comment: @JeremyThille: When hacking, think `eval`, I say. ;-)

Comment: @yeouuu: Yes. It keeps the variable, which is what you said you needed.

Comment: Oh I will use the second way. Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on a github fork that will explain the reason. When I'm ready i'll post a link.

Comment: There are several ways to do this without using `eval`. I really can't recommend them intelligently from such a small code snippet though.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth I won't use the eval method. It's evil ;-) But if you have other ways of doing this you can post a different answer.